# Euclidean and Manhattan distance with missing values

Tags: vector-spaces, euclidean-geometry

I wanted to know what is the correct way to calculate Euclidean and Manhattan distance. I've got a vector which has values from -120 to 0 (in dB). I have to compare it but sometimes one of the vectors can be missing value.
For example:

A = [-50, -40, -20, X, -10]

B = [-55, -44, X, -10, -12, -5]

Should I insert minimum value which is -120 here and calculate Euclidean distance?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Mathemagical what is unclear?

Comment: Should $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements? Is it signifikant that both $A$ and $B$ are (apart from the missing $X$) increasing?

Comment: hmm, I'm going to probably sort it from the highest to the lowest. They can have different number of elements - actually it's a dictionary with unique key and values that I want to put in a vector and compare.